# How to rename multiple files of different types?

Tags: python

im learning some Python and don't know how do to some things. I need rename some files and I found one video and get some explanation. this code, works 100%, to files of one type.

> import os
>
> path = os.chdir('E:\desenhos\aaahhmonstros')
>
> i = 0
> for file in os.listdir(path):
>
> new_file_name = f'{i}_aaahhmonstros.mp4'
> os.rename(file, new_file_name)
>
> i = i + 1

But i need do the same in a folder with 2 or more types of files. How do to that?

Comment: Are you sure it works 100%? The \a in your path is highly dubious